# How to find points on a curve which are nearest to a certain point

Tags: calculus

I'm asked to find the points on the curve 
$$y^2-2\sqrt{3}xy-x^2=2$$
Nearest to $(0,0)$.

I know there's a way you can do it by calculating the distance but what is confusing me is the $xy$ and when you get $d(x)$ for example you're going to have a $y$ term. So I don't know if i should partially differentiate or not?.

Comment: You want to minimize $x^2+y^2$ under the constraint provided by the curve. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Yeah so i would have to work in terms of one variable by replacing another so making x^2 in terms of y then solving that and then differentiate that and make it equal to 0

Comment: Depending on the course you are working with, you can probably use a method with Lagrange multipliers. Or derive local tangent space, find corresponding set of normal lines and find which of them intercept (0,0). It is possible to show that any differentiable manifold will have it's closest point to a point on the outside along some normal line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Differentiate the equation with respect to $x$:
$$2y\frac{dy}{dx}-2\sqrt3(x\frac{dy}{dx}+y)-2x=0$$
Solve for $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\sqrt3y+2x}{y-\sqrt3x}$$
Now, at a point $(x,y)$ closest to the origin, the gradient $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is perpendicular to the line from $(0,0)$ to $(x,y)$; that is, the gradient is $-\dfrac{x}{y}$. So solve the equation

$$\frac{\sqrt3y+2x}{y-\sqrt3x}=-\frac{x}{y}$$
to get $y$ in terms of $x$, and then plug this back into the original equation to get $x$ and $y$.

I don't guarantee the correctness of my algebra, but the method is sound.